# Determine value of $w$ in $\ddot{x}(t)+w^2x(t)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Given the differential equation:
>   $$\ddot{x}(t)+w^2x(t)=0$$
>   with initial conditions:
>   $$x(0)=1\qquad\dot{x}(0) = 0$$
>   what is the numerical value for $w$ if $x(2\pi)=\cosh2\pi$?

**My approach:**
Let $x=e^{rt}$
Then the differential becomes:
$e^{rt}(r^2+w^2)=0$
Then $r$ is:
$\pm wi$

Now:
$x(t)=A\cos(wt)+B\sin(wt)$ and given the initial conditions I end up with:

$x(t)=\cos(wt)$ // Maybe I went wrong here

But now:

$$x(2\pi)=\cos(w2\pi)=\cosh(2\pi)$$
Which cannot be. What is the simplest form of $w$?

Comment: $\omega=\pm i$, I guess. Look at Euler formula if the argument is a pure imaginary number.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, you please expand on your answer?

Comment: Your approach and its conclusion are correct: this cannot be. Just check that you have the correct values of  $x(0)$ and $x'(0)$ and the correct sign in $x''(t)+w^2x(t)$... and that your TA is not perverse enough to allow for complex values of $w$.

Comment: the generall solution is $$x \left( t \right) ={\it \_C1}\,\sin \left( wt \right) +{\it \_C2}\,
\cos \left( wt \right)
$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: This is actually already written in the question, with constants A and B.

Comment: sorry in a few minuts i will drive to Leipzig

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Still enough time to delete your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Solve 
$$
\cos(w2\pi)=\cosh(2\pi) \iff e^z+e^{-z}=e^{2\pi}+e^{-2\pi},
$$
$z=w2\pi$. This has the obvious solutions $e^z=e^{\pm2\pi}$. Since this is a quadratic equation in $e^z$ (after multiplying with $e^z$), there are no more solutions. Now the equation
$$
e^{iw2\pi}=e^{\pm2\pi}
$$
has the solutions 
$$
iw2\pi=\pm2\pi+i2\pi k\iff w=\mp i +k\text{ with }k\in\Bbb Z
$$